# IntelliJ Ignore Code Style for generated code

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm working on a project that has generated code inside of normal Java files. These files look something like this:

```
...

public class BCHLRS_Aggregate extends BAggregate {
  /*+ ------------ BEGIN END AUTO GENERATED CODE ------------ +*/
  ...
  /*+ ------------ BEGIN BAJA AUTO GENERATED CODE ------------ +*/

  ...
}
```

I would like to disable *all* CodeStyle formatting for anything between the `AUTO GENERATED CODE` comments. I've tried to accomplish this by setting custom formatted regexes:

[image: IntelliJ Settings]

Formatter off: `BEGIN BAJA AUTO GENERATED CODE`
Formatter on: `END BAJA AUTO GENERATED CODE`

This seems to help, but the methods inside of the comments are still being rearranged when I run `Reformat Code`.

Is there any way I can absolutely disable any code formatting for this generated code?

Comment: Shouldn't your "formatter off" trigger be different than your "formatter on" one?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Sorry for the confusion. I didn't notice that the text was scrolled in the input. I've updated the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have that order of generated code markers

```
public class BCHLRS_Aggregate extends BAggregate {
  ...
  /*+ ------------ BEGIN BAJA AUTO GENERATED CODE ------------ +*/

   // generated code

  /*+ ------------ BEGIN END AUTO GENERATED CODE ------------ +*/

  ...
}
```

Then your formatter control should look like this:
[image]

**Update**

`Rearange Code` and `Reformat Code` are different `Code Formatting Actions`.

See:
[image]

There are four different actions available:
[image]

The `Formatter Control` dosen't prevent the `Rearange Code` action from sorting your methods.

In Intellij IDEA CE and Ultimate, these two actions are separate actions.
When you execute the `Formate Code` actions, the code formatter is executed - declarations aren't rearanged.

Rearange code is only executed when you explicitly execute the `Rearange Code` action and that action doesn't respect the `Formatter Control` option.

Just downloaded Android Studio and it looks like this behaves the same way in there as well.

I don't know if this is intended or a bug.

Comment: This was a really good thought, but unfortunately, I don't think it's my problem. I didn't notice when I first posted the question that the text was scrolled inside of the inputs. I've updated my question now to better reflect the settings. Thanks for the response though!